# Python quit unexpectedly after `pipenv install`

Tags: python, pipenv

I am trying to install dependencies with `pipenv install` and receive modal letting me know that Python quit unexpectedly:

[image]

I have uninstalled python, and installed from https://www.python.org/downloads/ (not using homebrew)

Python version: 3.9.9 ;
OS: Monterey 12.0.1

Pipfile:

```
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
Flask = "==2.0.2"
flask-marshmallow = "==0.14.0"
Flask-SQLAlchemy = "==2.5.1"
marshmallow-sqlalchemy = "==0.26.1"
Flask-Migrate = "==3.1.0"
pytest = "==6.2.5"
pytest-testdox = "==2.0.1"
black = "==21.9b0"
pylint = "==2.11.1"
pylint-flask-sqlalchemy = "==0.2.0"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

Terminal output after command:

```
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
WARNING: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way
```

Could the problem be indicated by the failed locking? or loading libcrypto in an unsafe way?

Any one else run into something similar? Anything to try to resolve?

Thanks all

Comment: did you use sudo? if so, you may need sudo for all subsequent python commands

Comment: d'oh ... sudo seemed to have worked .. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Adding `sudo` before command removed the error modal .. thank you @Josh Sharkey